# how to add more listening port in FiddlerScript?

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore

Documentation says we can use QuickExec to start another port by manually typing: `!listen <port>`, how to listen in another port in Fiddlerscript?

more generally, can we do `Quickexec` in Fiddlerscript?

This kind of operation seems to be unsupported by the classes exposed by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `actQuickExec()` and automate it with the OnBoot callback:

```cs
static function OnBoot() {
    FiddlerApplication.UI.actQuickExec("!listen 443 your.domain");
}
```

Outside of FiddlerScript, you can use [ExecAction.exe](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledge-base/execaction) with command line arguments:

```bash
& "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Fiddler\ExecAction.exe" "!listen 443 your.domain"
```